# No Scrollable widget ancestor could be found

Tags: flutter, scrollable

I'm trying implementing of slidable list item by using [Slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) widget.

I get error that Scrollable.of() was called with a context that does not contain a Scrollable widget.

[image: Error Message]

I expect to get something like this:

[image: desire work]

my code looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Slidable(
          startActionPane: ActionPane(
            motion: const StretchMotion(),
            children: [
              SlidableAction(onPressed: ((context) {}), icon: Icons.waves),
            ],
          ),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: const ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.newspaper),
              title: Text("New List Tile"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `closeOnScroll: false` if the parent widget doesn't contains any scrollable widget.

```dart
Slidable(
  closeOnScroll: false, //this
  startActionPane: ActionPane(
```

Or you can use any scrollable widget on `body:`

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Slidable(
```

or

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Center(
      child: Slidable(
```

Just needed to be on top of Slidable. Doesn't have to be on body specifically.

[flutter_slidable/issues/402](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_slidable/issues/402)

Comment: in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kQHkBgjAAY) didn't use any Scrollable widget as I saw.. and the app works fine,Why?

Comment: ig depends on version and videos are most likely outdated.